# Suitable DB for browser extensions

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

We are developing the browser extensions for IE,FireFox,Chrome. When user is using this extension there are data required to be stored locally, and will be retrieved from local storage when there is need. We are thinking of using some light weight databases like HSQLDB,SQLLite or File System

```
Is there any light weight DB available which is independent of browsers ? or 
can file system be the better option here.
```

If suppose we are using the file system, then how good it is compared to DB based on performance, maintainability and so on for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite hands down without question.

Here is the bare bones of a SQLite Firefox restartless (bootstrap) addon for single database. [_template-BootstrapSQLite.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9225587)

Here are some resources, you don't have to use the barebones I put up above, apparently Mozilla handled that for you in SQLite.jsm.

Here are the resources:
[SQLite.jsm - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm)
[Storage Article - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage)

Comment: Hi Noitidart, How about for IE and Chrome? Will it holds good

Comment: I'm not sure I'm an ff guy. They should support SQLite its very common I know Android supports it for sure so Chrome definitely should.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent modern browser supports html5 web sql which is internally implemented with sqLite.  Chrome does so. However web sql is deprecated so not sure how long it will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) is a possible answer.

> IndexedDB is an API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data and for high performance searches on this data using indexes. While DOM Storage is useful for storing smaller amounts of data, it is less useful for storing larger amounts of structured data. IndexedDB provides a solution.

Unlike WebSQL it's [not deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), and enjoys decent cross-browser support.